# Finding initial conditions for DAE system of equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following DAE system of equations

```
\[Rho]0 = 1;
M = 1;
eq1 = D[m[t, r], r] - 4 Pi \[Rho][t, r] R[t, r]^2 D[R[t, r], r];
eq2 = D[m[t, r], t] + (4 Pi)/3 \[Rho][t, r] R[t, r]^2 D[R[t, r], t];
eq3 = D[R[t, r], r, t] - D[R[t, r], t] D[\[Nu][t, r], r] - 
   D[R[t, r], r] D[\[Lambda][t, r], t];
eq4 = D[\[Rho][t, r], r] + 1/4 \[Rho][t, r] D[\[Nu][t, r], r];
eq5 = Exp[-2 \[Nu][t, r]] (D[R[t, r], {t, 2}] - 
      D[\[Nu][t, r], t] D[R[t, r], t]) - 
   Exp[-2 \[Lambda][t, r]] D[\[Nu][t, r], r] D[R[t, r], r] + m[t, r]/
   R[t, r]^2 + (4 Pi)/3 \[Rho][t, r] R[t, r];
```

I have some problem finding initial conditions that produce solutions: how can I vary the initial conditions to see when the system has solutions? Currently I am just trying different random values, but it is obviously not the best method. I use `NDSolveValue` as follows:

```
NDSolveValue[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3 == 0, eq4 == 0, 
  eq5 == 0, \[Rho][0, r] == \[Rho]0, \[Rho][t, 0] == \[Rho]0, 
  m[0, r] == M, 
  m[t, 0] == 
   M, \[Nu][0, r] == -(1/4) Log[\[Rho]0], \[Nu][t, 
    0] == -(1/4) Log[\[Rho]0], \[Lambda][0, r] == 
   0, \[Lambda][t, 0] == 0, R[0, r] == ((3 M)/(4 Pi \[Rho]0))^(1/3), 
  R[t, 0] == ((3 M)/(4 Pi \[Rho]0))^(1/3), 
  Derivative[1, 0][R][0, r] == 1}, {\[Rho], R, 
  m, \[Nu], \[Lambda]}, {t, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Manipulate` for an easy search for appropriate initial conditions. This may inspire you how to do that.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[Sqrt[ic1] x] + ic2 Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}],
  {ic1, 1, 5, 1},
  {ic2, 0, 10, 1},
  ControlPlacement -> Top
 ]
```

`ic1` and `ic2` stand for two initial conditions to generate different plots.